# How are guillemets,i.e. « and », dealt with in cpp?

Tags: c++, character

I'm writing a c++ program that that cleans up certain scanned text. One of the common mistakes is the false insertion of « and » in a text. I can't figure out or find anywhere that talks about the representation of guillemets in cpp.
Currently, all I know is that they're not characters from the errors (EDIT: I misspoke. They're actually warnings).
Here's my code:

```
string modifyLine(string text)
{
    for(int i =0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (text[i]) {
            case '«':
                text.erase(text.begin()+i);
                break;
            case '»':
                text.erase(text.begin()+i);
                break;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

The warnings:

```
source_code.cpp:70:9: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   70 |    case '«':
      |         ^~~
source_code.cpp:73:13: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   73 |        case '»':
      |             ^~~
source_code.cpp: In function ‘std::string modifyLine(std::string)’:
source_code.cpp:70:4: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type [-Wswitch-outside-range]
   70 |    case '«':
      |    ^~~~
source_code.cpp:73:8: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type [-Wswitch-outside-range]
   73 |        case '»':
      |
```

Comment: What errors do you get? [Edit] the question to include them.

Comment: They're in the extended ASCII character set (codes 171 and 187). You'll need to cast `text[i]` to an `unsigned char` and use wide characters in the case statements (u`«`), or explicitly list the negative integers those characters will appear to be (-85 and -69, I think).

Comment: `«`' is 2 bytes, but `'` is used when size is 1 byte. I think you should cast `wchar_t` type.

Comment: You get a warning probably because the character encoding of your source code file is not a single-byte encoding (like Windows-1252), but a multibyte one (like UTF-8). The characters `«` and `»` can have different byte representations, depending on the character encoding scheme used. For example, in Windows-1252, a guillemet is encoded with just one byte: either `0xAB` (for `«`) or `0xBB` (for `»`). But in UTF-8, a guillemet requires two code units: byte sequences `0xC2, 0xAB` (for `«`) or `0xC2, 0xBB` (for `»`). A variable of `char` type can only hold a single byte, not a two-byte sequence.

Comment: @heapunderrun Yours should be the top comment, if not an answer